# Regular expressions in Groovy - extract part before first underscore only

Tags: regex, groovy

Given is a string variable elementOne.

```
def elemenOne = 'AB_CD_EF_GH'
```

The challenge is to extract only the 'AB', the first part of its value, only that which precedes the first underscore symbol (counted from the left to right).

I have written a code:

```
def elementTwo = (element_one =~ /^.*(?=(_))/)[0][0]
```

but it extracts 'AB_CD_EF' instead of only 'AB'.

How should I modify my code, in order to extract only 'AB' part from 'AB_CD_EF_GH'?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `^[^_]+(?=_)` See https://regex101.com/r/6aPa1O/1

Comment: `.*` is greedy, use a lazy one, `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regexp for this...  Which can end up with code that's easier to read later on...

Here's some techniques...  The last one is a regexp method

```
def elemenOne = 'AB_CD_EF_GH'

assert 'AB' == elemenOne.takeWhile { it != '_' }
assert 'AB' == elemenOne.split('_').head()
assert 'AB' == (elemenOne =~ '([^_]+)_.*')[0][1]
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are details missing that might affect your decision about how best to do this but for a starting point, this will evaluate to the result you are looking for...

```
def inputString = 'AB_CD_EF_GH'

def match = (inputString =~ /^[^_]+(?=_)/)[0]

println match
```